# Boto3 API RDS: get list of params accepted by function

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

I am using the boto3 API, particularly the RDS client, to modify an RDS instance based on a list of parameters and their associated values. Prior to calling the `modify_db_instance()` function, I want to validate the user-provided parameters to ensure that they can be passed to the modify function (the parameters will also be used elsewhere; thus, they may be accepted by some boto functions but not others).

If I were to execure the modify function and provide an invalid parameter, I would receive a `ParamValidationError` from boto, as well as a list of all of the acceptable parameters. I would like to retrieve this list programmatically. Boto3 docs suggest I use the `describe_valid_db_instance_modifications()` function - the response I get is indeed similar to what is described in the docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_valid_db_instance_modifications), but I'm explicitly looking for a list of params, which I don't get from that function. I cannot figure out a way to programmatically do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The valid arguments for these boto3 functions are not hardcoded into the function signature itself, so this is a little trickier than using something like `inspect.getargspec`. This is certainly a little convoluted, but works:

```
import urllib3
import json

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boto/botocore/develop/botocore/data/rds/2014-10-31/service-2.json'

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', url)
data = json.loads(r.data)
print(data['shapes']['ModifyDBInstanceMessage']['members'].keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

boto3 does expose the models for you, but you have to dig deep:

```py
allowed_keys = dict(client.meta.service_model
  .operation_model("ModifyDBInstanceMessage").input_shape.members).keys()
```

This works for any model for the client type, but you do have to find the service-2.json to figure out the name.